# Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Any?' and 'String' Swift iOS

Tags: ios, json, swift, binary-operators

I have this `var json : [[String : Any]] = [[:]]` which contains the JSON response as follows:

```
{
"id": "1",
"name": "Apple",
"category_name": "Fruits"
},
{
"id": "2",
"name": "Black shirt",
"category_name": "Fashion"
},
{
"id": "3",
"name": "iPad",
"category_name": "Gadgets"
}
```

And I wrote an enum:

```
enum : Int {
        case fruits = 0, fashion, gadgets
    }

var data = [Categories: [[String: Any]]]()
```

Then I have this method to sort the categories:

```
func sortData() {
        data[.fruits] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Fruits" })
        data[.fashion] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Fashion" })
        data[.gadgets] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Gadgets" })
    }
```

After that I get an error like this

> Binary operator '`==`' cannot be applied to operands of type '`Any?`' and
>   '`String`'

Please tell me how do I solve that one?

Comment: you can try like $0["category_name"] as? String == "Fruits"..

Comment: If the json responds only contains values that are of type `String`, you can change `data` to use `[String: String]` and save yourself from doing this casting.

Comment: Swift is an object oriented language. Why don't you use a custom struct or class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should safely cast the value on the left to `String`, like this:

```
data[.fruits] = self.json.filter({ ($0["category_name"] as? String) == "Fruits" })
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you're trying to compare values of differing types, namely `Any?` and `String`. To quickly solve the problem you might want to try and convince Swift that your `Any?` is actually a string value. Try replacing `$0["category_name"]` with `($0["category_name"] as? String)`, which will turn it into `String?`. Swift will then be able to compare the optional string with your given category string.

Comment: I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

Change following codes from

```
func sortData() {
        data[.fruits] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Fruits" })
        data[.fashion] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Fashion" })
        data[.gadgets] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] == "Gadgets" })
    }
```

to

```
func sortData() {
        data[.fruits] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] as? String  == "Fruits" })
        data[.fashion] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] as? String == "Fashion" })
        data[.gadgets] = self.json.filter({ $0["category_name"] as? String == "Gadgets" })
    }
```

This will fix the error.